# Transfer files between google-drive and one drive

Tags: javascript, python, google-drive-api, onedrive, movefile

I have more than 10TB of content in my google shared drive  I want to copy all that content in my onedrive account. I tried mover.io but it's not working for me. What should I do. Also tried google colab but I couldn't find great code of python

It's been 2nd day and I couldn't find anything that works properly and fast.

I don't want to use any 3rd-party mover like multi-cloud ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temporary RDP through GitHub action, in that RDP you will get a high-speed internet connection, download the file in it, and upload it to onedrive.
you can also use rabb.it